# hide part of the content of an element

Tags: javascript, text, hide, element

Sorry, this may be kind of weird problem:

I have an existing HTML code, which I can not directly edit or delete parts of it. The problem is: Inside a div-element in this code, there is some text which I want to hide. There are also another element inside of this div, which I don't want to hide. It looks something like this:

```
<div>
....Text I want to hide....
<table> ... Text I don't want to hide...</table>
</div>
```

My question: Is it possible to hide the "....Text I want to hide...." while not hiding the "... Text I don't want to hide..."? (for example using javascript?)

Comment: Encase the text you want to hide in a span and hide the span..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *remove* the text, you can write:

```
div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
```

(where `div` is a variable referring to this `<div>` element).

If you want to wrap it in a `<span>` that you can then hide and unhide at will, you can write:

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
div.insertBefore(span, div.firstChild);
span.appendChild(div.firstChild);
```

(where `div` is as before).

Answer (score 3):

```
var txt = div.childNodes[0];
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(txt);
var span = document.createElement("span")
range.surroundContents(span);
span.style.display = "none";
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KZVDf/

Answer (score 0):

Surround text which you want to hide with `span` and set to that `span display:none`. Example:

```
<div>
<span style="display:none">....Text I want to hide....</span>
<table> ... Text I don't want to hide...</table>
</div>
```

Or make it with hidden with script:

```
$('div span').show(); // Show hidden text in span
$('div span').hide(); // Hide text in span
```